# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error in the Servlet code

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I'm having java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error after executing the above code.I will be very glad if someone could look into this code. I'm using oracle 11g database and all database connection details are correct. Also having HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error on while executing the code.

```
 import java.io.*;  
    import java.sql.*;  
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
    import javax.servlet.http.*; 



     public class Search extends HttpServlet {  

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                throws ServletException, IOException {  



        response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String rollno=request.getParameter("roll");  
    int roll=Integer.valueOf(rollno);

        try{  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from result where rollno=?");  
    ps.setInt(1,roll);  

    out.print("<table width=50% border=1>");  
    out.print("<caption>Result:</caption>");  



     ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

    /* Printing column names */  
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();  
    int total=rsmd.getColumnCount();  
    out.print("<tr>");  
    for(int i=1;i<=total;i++)  
    {  
    out.print("<th>"+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+"</th>");  
    }  



     out.print("</tr>");

        out.print("</tr>");  

    /* Printing result */  

    while(rs.next())  
    {  
    out.print("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"  
    </td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td></tr>");  

    }  


        out.print("</table>");  

    }catch (Exception e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}  

    finally{out.close();}  

    }  
    }  

   I'm using oracle 11g database and all database connection details are correct.
```

I'm using oracle 11g database and all database connection details are correct.

Comment: show full stacktrace of your exceptions

Comment: can you add the error also? what is being printed on the console?

Comment: The JAR file with the (Oracle) JDBC driver must be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder.

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007, but you do need the Oracle JDBC driver JAR on the classpath somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you should add JDBC driver into the build path , Or add it as a dependency to your POM